# Magento Database Changes

Tags: magento2, database, attributes, migration

I want to ask those who made the **Migration from version 1.9 to version 2.0.2** what are the most database changes the names of tables affected and the attributes.

Comment: Not knowing the specifics this could be interesting for you : https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

Comment: yes but  i want to know exactly the tables  changed